# jquery appendTo loses text outside html element

Tags: jquery

My ajax looks like this:

```
//get ajax hint count
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "actions.php",
                            type: "GET",
                            data: "get_hint_count=1",
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (data){
                                $(".hint").empty();
                                $(data).appendTo(".hint");
                            }
                        });
```

and data contains:

```
?<span class="tooltip">Hint is available to registered users only</span>
```

But this line:

```
$(data).appendTo(".hint");
```

appends only what is inside `.tooltip`. `?` disappears

Why?

Comment: Is this what your expected result is? http://jsfiddle.net/V5F9m/. You mean to keep the "?" in the markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As DanC says, `$()` does not support creating a document fragment with leading text nodes.

However, [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) does not suffer from this limitation, so you can invert your logic and write:

```
success: function(data) {
    $(".hint").empty().append(data);
}
```

Which is equivalent to a single call to [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
success: function(data) {
    $(".hint").html(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are losing that character outiside the span is documented in the jQuery docs:

from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

When passing HTML to jQuery(), please also note that text nodes are not treated as DOM elements. With the exception of a few methods (such as .content()), they are generally otherwise ignored or removed. E.g:

```
var el = $( "1<br/>2<br/>3" ); // returns [<br>, "2", <br>]
el  = $( "1<br/>2<br/>3 >" ); // returns [<br>, "2", <br>, "3 &gt;"]
```

This behavior is expected.

You could try doing something like wrapping what you are receiving, for example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "actions.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: "get_hint_count=1",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data){
        $(".hint").empty();
        $('<div>' + data + '</div>').appendTo(".hint");
    }
});
```